$\|B\|_{op} \le \|A\|_{op}$ when $B_{i,j} = v_i^TAv_j$
I'm currently stuck to the following statement.

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are only 0 or 1,  and let $B$ be $n\times n$ matrix such that $B_{i,j} = v_i^TAv_j$ for some $v_i\in\mathbb R^n,\quad i=1,\dots,n$. Then we have
$$\|B\|_{op} \le \|A\|_{op}.$$

I first think of the property
$$\|A\|_{op} = \sup_{x,y\in\mathbb R^n: \|x\|=\|y\|=1}x^TAy,$$but there is no restriction of the norm of $v_i$, so this can't be used. I also tried to use the Frobenius norm to the $B$
$$\|B\|_{op}^2 \le \|B\|_{F}^2 = \sum_i\sum_j(v_j^TAv_j)^2,$$ but this doesn't give any useful information regarding the desired result.
Any help regarding how to obtain the desired result would be grateful. Thank you

This is obviously false. By definition, you have $B=V^TAV$ in matrix form. When $B$ happens to be nonzero, you will eventually get $|B|>|A|$ if you scale $V$ by a sufficiently large factor. However, by the submultiplicativity of the operator norm, the inequality is true when $|V|_2\le1$.

Ah, then there must be some omission regarding the norm of $V$ (estimated as $V:=[v_1\ v_2 \dots \ v_n]$). Thank you for your help.
